# Rxjs / AngularFire2: unsubscribe(): "TypeError: Illegal Invocation"

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I get an error "Illegal Invocation" when I try to unsubscribe from within this rxjs observer.

```
let s = names.subscribe((a:Array<any>) => {
    s.unsubscribe();
    if(a.length){ reject('name exists') }
}
```

The *names* variable is of type [*FirebaseListObservable*](https://angularfire2.com/api/classes/_utils_firebase_list_observable_.firebaselistobservable.html)

Setting some breakpoints, i can see that the observer function (callback) is being called immediately. Any code following this subscription is run AFTER the callback has already run once. The *s* variable is undefined, therefore, within the callback.

What am i doing wrong here? Shouldnt the observable wait till next tick? Should i do it manually?

*UPDATE:* wrapping the callback code in a setTimeout(*code*, 0) got rid of the error. It seems strange that I should have to do this though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When* the `next` block gets executed is completely implementation dependent. The point of having a callback is that your code shouldn't have to concern itself with *when* the event arrives, only *what* should happen when it does.

If you need only the first item from the stream then you could use either `take(1)` or `first()` instead:

```
let s = names.first().subscribe((a:Array<any>) => {
    if(a.length){ reject('name exists') }
}
```